# DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon has no effect

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am attempting to run Docker for Windows but don't seem to be able to switch to linux containers.

Reference: https://stefanscherer.github.io/run-linux-and-windows-containers-on-windows-10/

**Steps**

Start the daemon

```powershell
choco install -y docker-desktop
restart-computer
cd 'c:\program files\docker\docker\resources'
.\dockerd
```

```
time="..." level=info msg="Starting up"
time="..." level=info msg="Windows default isolation mode: process"
time="..." level=info msg="Restoring existing overlay networks from HNS into docker"
time="..." level=info msg="Loading containers: done."time="..." level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=74b1e89 graphdriver(s)=windowsfilter version=19.03.1
time="..." level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
time="..." level=info msg="API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine"
```

I see it is running 'windowsfilter' (unexpected, but OK). So I try to start some containers

```powershell
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu bash
cd c:\program files\docker\docker
./DockerCli -SwitchDaemon
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu bash
./DockerCli -SwitchLinuxEngine
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu bash
```

All of which result in the message...

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'
```

For the record, I can run windows containers.

Answer (score 1):

(Part of) the problem was that I had started `./dockerd` manually. I shouldn't have done that, but the confusion originated back with the install of docker.

For some reason the actual docker daemon was not responding. This was resolved by starting an admin prompt and restarting the daemon.

```
Start-Process "powershell" -verb RunAs
Restart-Service com.docker.service;
Restart-Service Docker;
```

Now, from a non-admin prompt

```
& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchLinuxEngine
docker run -p 80:80 -d nginx
& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchWindowsEngine
docker run --rm -p 81:80 --name aspnetcore_sample mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
```

Results in two running containers that both respond to requests.

Comment: FWIW it looks like DockerCLI is an undocumented tool as per https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1269 however I can confirm that as of Docker Desktop 3.1.0 (51484) the commands `-SwitchLinuxEngine` and `-SwitchWindowsEngine` work as expected.